# Getting min_element of from a vector of structs based on two variables

Tags: c++, vector, struct, std

So I have a vector of structs that is defined and used in the following manner:

```
enum ID {
    alpha,
    beta,
    gamma
};

using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;

typedef struct pInfo {
    int bar;
    int key;
    ID id;
    TimePoint tPoint;
} pInfo;

std::vector<pInfo> pMembers;
```

I would like to basically iterate through this vector after populating it with all the items and get a reference to the matching element that meets my criteria.

The criteria is that I would have a function that passes in a type of ID, and it will return a reference to the vector element that is the best fit which means the one with the lowest `TimePoint`.

So for reference the function would be something like: `pInfo& getNext(ID p_id);`

And if I have a vector that has a few elements of each, like 4 `alpha`, 4 `gamma`, 4 `beta` I want the function to only check the ones with `ID == alpha` if that's what I pass in.

Right now I was using something like this:

```
std::min_element(std::begin(pMembers), std::end(pMembers), [](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs){return lhs.tPoint < rhs.tPoint};
```

But this doesn't account for me wanting to only get certain types.

How would I do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the lambda capture the passed ID so it can be used in the comparisons, eg:

```
pInfo& getNext(ID p_id)
{
    if (pMembers.empty())
        throw ...; // nothing to search, can't return a reference to nothing, so throw an exception instead...

    auto iter = std::min_element(std::begin(pMembers), std::end(pMembers),
        [=](const pInfo &lhs, const pInfo &rhs)
        {
            if (lhs.id == p_id) {
                if (rhs.id != p_id) return true;
            }
            else if (rhs.id == p_id) {
                if (lhs.id != p_id) return false;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
            return lhs.tPoint < rhs.tPoint;
        }
    );

    if (iter->id != p_id)
        throw ...; // p_id not found, can't return a reference to nothing, so throw an exception instead...

    return *iter;
}
```

Alternatively, try something more like this:

```
pInfo& getNext(ID p_id)
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<pInfo>> v;

    std::copy_if(std::begin(pMembers), std::end(pMembers), std::back_inserter(v),
        [=](const pInfo &item){ return item.id == p_id; }
    );
    if (v.empty())
        throw ...; // p_id not found, can't return a reference to nothing, so throw an exception instead...

    auto iter = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
        [](const pInfo &lhs, const pInfo &rhs){ return lhs.tPoint < rhs.tPoint; }
    );
    return *iter;
}
```

Comment: And the last line of returning `iter->get();` throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

I would just store the objects with different IDs in different vectors, one vector for each ID:

```
std::map<ID, std::vector<pInfo>> pMembers;
```

If you can't or won't do that, then I'd use a filtering iterator adaptor. The following example uses Boost.Iterator:

```
auto const filter = [p_id](auto const& id) { return id == p_id; };
auto const compare = [](auto const& a, auto const& b) { return a.tPoint < b.tPoint; };

auto const it = std::min_element(boost::make_filter_iterator(filter, begin(pMembers), end(pMembers)),
                                 boost::make_filter_iterator(filter,   end(pMembers), end(pMembers)),
                                 compare).base();
```

Expanding on Remy's answer, this is how I would write their first way of doing it:

```
auto const it = std::min_element(begin(pMembers), end(pMembers), [=](auto const& a, auto const& b)
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(a.id != p_id, a.tPoint)
         < std::forward_as_tuple(b.id != p_id, b.tPoint);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply apply the range-based-for to this problem as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yQ5tFgiNREOeT0jG)

```
const pInfo& getNext(const std::vector<pInfo>& pMembers, ID p_id)
{
    const pInfo* p{nullptr};
    TimePoint min{TimePoint::max()};

    for(const auto& p_i : pMembers)
    {
        if(p_i.id == p_id && p_i.tPoint < min)
        {
            min = p_i.tPoint;
            p = &p_i;
        }
    }

    if(!p){
        throw std::runtime_error("no data.");
    }

    return *p;
}
```